# IPC between 64-bit and 32-bit installations

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have two different packages that I need to run in ROS (fuerte), but one works correctly in the 32-bit installation, while the other works only in the 64-bit installation. I do not have the skill set to force either package into the opposing version of ROS.

So, can I run two computers, one with a 32-bit installation and the other with 64-bit, and communicate between them normally? In other words, can I set up a standard roscore on one machine and have the other simply feed data to it?

I've been trying to test this with simulated data, and gotten some errors - but I'm not sure if it was because the difference in 32 vs 64 bit, or because I made some other mistake. And, unfortunately, I need to answer this question before buying the sensor, so I can't test it in hardware yet.

Thank you in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54679/ipc-between-64-bit-and-32-bit-installations/) by [ebbeowulf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4156/ebbeowulf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2013-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Since ROS message exchange is based on TCP-sockets, it shouldn't be a problem mixing 32- and 64-bit computers. We are using two 64-bit clients with a 32-bit roscore ourselves, because we need a 32-bit only CANBus driver on our robot.

But you should consider, that depending on your sensor, the network connection can become a bottleneck. So if your sensor requires some heavy bandwidth you may be forced to go the painful way and port one of your components.

---

Originally posted by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) with karma: 2510 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1